# Ask for user password through Zenity just once in bash script

Tags: bash, function, sudo, zenity

I'm creating a bash script to perform some tasks stored in an array, and some of them need elevated permissions. This is my working current approach using Zenity:

```
#!/bin/bash

functions=("function1")
functions+=("function2")

function1()
{
    password=$1 

    echo $password | sudo -S fdisk -l
}

function2()
{
    password=$1 

    echo $password | sudo -S fdisk -l
}

password=$(zenity --password)

for i in ${!functions[@]}
do
    ${functions[$i]} $password
done
```

But I would like to avoid passing the password every time, something similar to this:

```
#!/bin/bash

functions=("function1")
functions+=("function2")

function1()
{
    sudo -S fdisk -l
}

function2()
{
    sudo -S fdisk -l
}

password=$(zenity --password)

# Become superuser here with given password

for i in ${!functions[@]}
do
    ${functions[$i]}
done
```

I know the usual approach is to have a separated script, but in this case I need the work to be done in just one script. I have tried this:

```
echo $password | sudo -S ${functions[$i]}
```

But then bash throws a "sudo: function1: order not found" error. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Edit: the goal here is either to become superuser at one point and mantain sudo privileges (without calling the script with sudo) or just use the password variable in only one line of code. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a global variable.

```
functions=("function1")
functions+=("function2")

function1()
{    
    echo "$password" | sudo -S fdisk -l
}

function2()
{    
    echo "$password" | sudo -S fdisk -l
}

password=$(zenity --password)

for i in ${!functions[@]}
do
    ${functions[$i]}
done
```

Comment: That solution still makes me use the password variable with every command.

Comment: It sets `password` once, and you can use it with the commands that require it. If your goal is to run `sudo` without even *asking* for a password, that requires you to configure `sudo` vi the `/etc/sudoers` file to specify who can run which commands without a password. Such configuration is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ok, I guess that I was asking for the imposible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how viable this is, but I put the password in a secure text file and have the password entered into a variable using cat each time the script is run:

`password=$(echo cat /usr/sec_pass)`

and then use the ${password} to send the password through the pipe to the commands.